# custom events for handle new object create with ajax call?

Tags: jquery, events

I have a page with a div that load the content from a php script called with jquery/ajax.
The content is essentially a file/ folder tree.
I need to make these droppable/draggable so I used the .draggable and .droppable jquery's functions. I wrap all in $(window).load  (with document.ready doesn't work maybe the ajax call thatr create the elements is called before the js).
In this page there is a timer that after 5 minute update the content of the div calling the same function via ajax/jquery.
After the update the drag/drop doesn't work anymore, is the problem that jquery can't handle new created object.
So what I have to do to make the things right?
Should I create a new event after every update and bind the drag/drop on this custom event with .bind/.trigger ?

Hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for this.

Comment: ok but I need to create a new event when the ajax call is completed isn't it? if not on wich event I have to bind the live

Comment: You only need to declare that event with your jQuery selector on page load. When new elements (by AJAX for example) are added to the page, jQuery will automatically detect these new ones and bind the event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you took a look at the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin? IT handles the ajax request, drag and drop and the themeing for you.

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI draggable and such or writing it from scratch?

Comment: I'm using the jquery's ui library